# rewrite rule to switch to subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm deploying a Wordpress blog, but I don't want to overwrite the current site yet.

public_html/*.* <-- the current site

public_html/wp/*.* <-- the new site

How must my .htaccess look like so I can seamlessly switch from the current site to the new one
so that http://domain.tld shows the new site like it would be directly in the public_html folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it applies to your situation, but wouldn't it be simpler to just do a series of move operations in your FTP client?

1. Create directory `/public_html/old/`
2. Move everything except for `/public_html/wp` into `/public_html/old`
3. Move everything from `/public_html/wp` up one level

done!

You'd have to be very careful when doing the moving of course.

If that won't work, I don't know what kind of hosting environment you are in, but the easiest way to do would be to map your domain to `public_html/wp` instead of `public_html`. That can't be done in `.htaccess` though, you will need some kind of access to the site's setup.

In `.htaccess`, you will probably have to use a `mod_rewrite` rule that *could* look something like this (I can't test this right now so no guarantees.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp
RewriteRule (.*) /wp/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: that would work as well, but thought a rewrite makes switching easier

Comment: @Midday I added a (untested) rewrite.

Comment: @Midday I would prefer moving in any case because it's cleaner. Rewrite rules make things harder to maintain, you may get in trouble with absolute paths in your new WP config, and cost a bit of performance.